# How to Set Elasticsearch 5 Memory (Heap) Size When Running as a Service

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 5.x running as a service, how do I set the memory (heap) size?

The environment variables

```
ES_MIN_MEM   ES_MAX_MEM    ES_HEAP_SIZE
```

are not being read or taken into account when Elasticsearch is started as a service through Systemd on Debian-based distros (Ubuntu, Mint, etc) using

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Answer (score 8):

In ElasticSearch 5.x, after **October 26, 2016** the old methods to set memory size do not work anymore.

For example: after changing ES_HEAP_SIZE in /etc/default/elasticsearch and in etc/init.d/elasticsearch, if you run
`ps aux | grep elasticsearch` you will still get

`/usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g` Meaning 2G min and 2G max RAM

You have to make the changes in

```
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
```

`Xms` represents the initial size of total heap space
`Xmx` represents the maximum size of total heap space
 so change them according to your needs, for example:

> -Xms16g
>
> -Xmx16g

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) on deciding the right size (still showing the old variable and file names at the time of writing)

the default setting in Elasticsearch 5 are -Xms2g  -Xmx2g

Comment: By the way, Elasticsearch 5 installed through the Debian installer seems to be using Systemd rather than init.d to autostart, so the config file for the service would be in /usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service